# From a list of links, on click, make the clicked link, the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown, that shows different cities. Here's the code for the dropdown:

```
<ul class="nav-poplist">
<li class="nav_divider_before"><a onclick="set_city(1);" href="javascript:">Bangalore</a></li>                    
<li><a onclick="set_city(3);" href="javascript:">Hyderabad</a></li>            
</ul>
```

So, currently the order is like:
**Bangalore**
**Hyderabad**
So, what I'm trying to do is, when the user clicks on Hyderabad, then Hyderabad should come on top, and Bangalore (and other cities that might be there in future) should go down, eg. Suppose user clicks on Hyderabad, then the order should be,
**Hyderabad**
**Bangalore**
i.e., The link that is clicked should become the first element, and the rest should go down.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm actually quite new to jquery & javascript, so I don't have much clue regarding this.

Comment: Once thing I can assure you is that this behaviour will cause a lot of confusion for the users.  Imagine: you have a list of things on the page - and this list changes every time you click on one item.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot for the tip.
I have modified this behaviour. Now, there is a default text as Bangalore, and when you hover over it, you see a dropdown as Bangalore & Hyderabad, so when you click on Hyderabad, the text will change to Hyderabad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `prepend` method:

```
$('.nav-poplist li').click(function(){
   $('.nav-poplist').prepend(this)
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SQQY7/

Comment: Never knew that `.prepend()`ing an existing element just moved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by adding the following line to your `set_city()` function:

```
$(this).parent().prependTo($(this).parent().parent());
```